# How to select from mysql record then add the amount together?

Tags: php, mysql

What I try to ask is how to select from database record and my php code add the amount together.

here is my select mysql part:

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT amount FROM item");
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$totalamount= $res['amount'];
echo $totalamount;
}
```

my database got 4 records so it echo out is 1.002.003.001.50 , also as know as 1.00 2.00 3.00 1.50

I must using loop because it got a lot records in my database,so how can I add all this echo out answer become 7.80?

Thanks

Comment: srsly? did you try adding them together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you try to do like this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as total_ammount from item
```

Is this what you need?
btw: you should not use loop, because it will take a lot of time for rendering, especialy if you want just the ammount ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT amount FROM item");
        $totalamount=0;
        while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        $tableamount= $res['amount'];
        $totalamount=$totalamount+$tableamount;
        }
        echo $totalamount;
```